# Jasper Reports PDF Export - Displaying SVG image from embedded URL

Tags: svg, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

Here is the sample report

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="sample" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="80b32d69-a3a5-4132-afef-37bc11966113">
<parameter name="img" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<detail>
    <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
        <image hAlign="Left" isUsingCache="true">
            <reportElement uuid="80c1fb9b-31c1-4755-941a-f100059e488d" x="11" y="10" width="522" height="83"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{img}]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
    </band>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```

It returns the error:

```
Byte data not found at : data:image/svg+xml;base64, ...
```

while rendering in PDF, though works only on HTML exports.
As suggested in some posts, I tried using

```
net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.BatikRenderer.getInstance(new java.net.URL("data:..."))
```

but it didn't work either.

Could someone suggest a method that will display the embedded image in all types of exports?

Answer (score 2):

I have finally solved problem of embedding SVG in Jasper PDF report.

Use raw SVG image data without `data:image/svg+xml;base64`.

Use `net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.BatikRenderer` to render SVG image. Maven dependency including this class is following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Use fully qualified class names `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` instead of `Base64`. Maven dependency including this class is following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Jasper jrxml shold look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="sample" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="80b32d69-a3a5-4132-afef-37bc11966113">
<parameter name="img" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9Im5vIj8+PCFET0NUWVBFIHN2ZyBQVUJMSUMgIi0vL1czQy8vRFREIFNWRyAxLjEvL0VOIiAiaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvR3JhcGhpY3MvU1ZHLzEuMS9EVEQvc3ZnMTEuZHRkIj48c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4xIiB3aWR0aD0iMjQ0IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjgyIj48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9IiMwMDAwMDAiIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iMiIgc3Ryb2tlLWxpbmVjYXA9InJvdW5kIiBzdHJva2UtbGluZWpvaW49InJvdW5kIiBkPSJNIDEgMzcgYyAwIC0wLjIxIC0wLjUyIC04LjEzIDAgLTEyIGMgMC43OSAtNS45NSAyLjMxIC0xMi42OCA0IC0xOCBjIDAuNDYgLTEuNDQgMS45IC0yLjkgMyAtNCBjIDAuOCAtMC44IDEuOTggLTEuODggMyAtMiBjIDMuOTYgLTAuNDcgOS40IC0wLjUgMTQgMCBjIDcuNjggMC44MyAxNS43NiAyLjM5IDIzIDQgYyAxLjM5IDAuMzEgMi44MyAxLjE0IDQgMiBjIDMuNzMgMi43MyA3Ljc4IDUuNzggMTEgOSBjIDEuOTUgMS45NSA0LjA2IDQuNjUgNSA3IGMgMC44OCAyLjIxIDAuMzkgNS41NiAxIDggYyAwLjM0IDEuMzUgMS44OCAyLjY3IDIgNCBjIDAuNDkgNS4zNSAxLjE5IDEyLjkgMCAxOCBjIC0wLjkyIDMuOTQgLTguNTYgMTAuMzggLTcgMTIgYyAzLjkyIDQuMDggMjEuMjUgOS43IDMyIDE0IGMgMi41NCAxLjAxIDUuMzUgMS43OCA4IDIgYyA1LjE1IDAuNDMgMTAuODQgMC43MiAxNiAwIGMgOC45MiAtMS4yNCAxOC4yIC0zLjY3IDI3IC02IGMgMi40MiAtMC42NCA0LjYxIC0yLjI1IDcgLTMgYyAyLjkgLTAuOTEgNi4yOSAtMC44MiA5IC0yIGMgNi45NyAtMy4wMiAxNC4yMSAtNy4wMiAyMSAtMTEgYyAyLjg2IC0xLjY4IDYuMDYgLTMuODYgOCAtNiBjIDEuMDUgLTEuMTUgMS44MSAtMy4zNSAyIC01IGMgMC40MyAtMy42NyAwLjc0IC04LjY3IDAgLTEyIGMgLTAuNDUgLTIgLTIuNDkgLTQuMTggLTQgLTYgYyAtMS43OCAtMi4xNCAtMy43OCAtNC42NCAtNiAtNiBjIC0zLjQgLTIuMDggLTguMDIgLTQuMTUgLTEyIC01IGMgLTQuOTEgLTEuMDUgLTEwLjkgLTAuMyAtMTYgLTEgYyAtMi4wMSAtMC4yNyAtNC4wNyAtMS45IC02IC0yIGMgLTQuMjkgLTAuMjEgLTkuMjYgMC41MyAtMTQgMSBjIC0yLjA2IDAuMjEgLTQuMTEgMC40MSAtNiAxIGMgLTMuMzUgMS4wNSAtNi41MiAyLjkyIC0xMCA0IGMgLTExLjc3IDMuNjYgLTI5LjQzIDcuMyAtMzUgMTAgYyAtMC45NyAwLjQ3IDEuMDcgNC41MiAyIDYgYyAwLjUzIDAuODQgMi4xNyAxLjE3IDMgMiBjIDYuMDEgNi4wMSAxMS41NiAxMy44MSAxOCAxOSBjIDUuMDcgNC4wOCAxMS44MiA3LjEgMTggMTAgYyA0LjQ3IDIuMDkgOS4yOSAzLjk3IDE0IDUgYyA1LjczIDEuMjUgMTEuNzQgMS4zNSAxOCAyIGMgMy44MiAwLjQgNy4yNSAwLjkyIDExIDEgYyAxMy4yNSAwLjI3IDI2LjcyIDEuMTIgMzkgMCBjIDUuMjggLTAuNDggMTAuOTMgLTMuMDcgMTYgLTUgYyAxLjc2IC0wLjY3IDMuODkgLTEuNjkgNSAtMyBjIDIuMjMgLTIuNjMgNC4zNSAtNi41NCA2IC0xMCBjIDEuNjUgLTMuNDcgMy4xMiAtNy40NyA0IC0xMSBjIDAuMzggLTEuNTEgLTAuMzQgLTMuNDUgMCAtNSBjIDAuOTMgLTQuMjEgMy4wNyAtOC43OSA0IC0xMyBsIDAgLTUiLz48L3N2Zz4="]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<detail>
    <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
        <image hAlign="Left" isUsingCache="true">
            <reportElement uuid="80c1fb9b-31c1-4755-941a-f100059e488d" x="11" y="10" width="522" height="83"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.BatikRenderer.getInstance(new org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64().decodeBase64($P{img}))]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
    </band>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: The process is the same for png and gif images ? I`m trying for two days with no succes.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it with a svg but I got it working with a png image.
You have to add the import `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` and you should remove the Header from the base64 encoded data: `data:image/svg+xml;base64,`

Now you can decode and pass the data with this Expression: `new ByteArrayInputStream(new Base64().decodeBase64($P{logo}.getBytes("UTF-8")))`.

In your case it should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="sample" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="80b32d69-a3a5-4132-afef-37bc11966113">
<import value="org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64"/>
<parameter name="img" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["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"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<detail>
    <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
        <image hAlign="Left" isUsingCache="true">
            <reportElement uuid="80c1fb9b-31c1-4755-941a-f100059e488d" x="11" y="10" width="522" height="83"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[new ByteArrayInputStream(new Base64().decodeBase64($P{img}.getBytes("UTF-8")))]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
    </band>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```