# Create PDF file with embedded SVG in Java

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have an SVG file and I need to create a PDF that has the SVG embedded. I tried with Apache PDFBox (see below) but I get an error saying that "SVG files are not supported". Any ideas how to create a PDF with an embedded SVG? It doesn't have to be with PDFBox, and I prefer not to convert the SVG to an image file.

```
    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    doc.addPage(page);
    
    PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("C:/chart.svg", doc);
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
    contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 70, 250);
    contentStream.close();
    doc.save("C:/chart.pdf");
    doc.close();
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Image
> type not supported: chart.svg     at
> org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject.createFromFileByExtension(PDImageXObject.java:257)
> at
> org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject.createFromFile(PDImageXObject.java:202)
> at testjava.TestPdfBox.main(TestPdfBox.java:18)

Comment: maybe try jasper reports https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261394/jasper-reports-pdf-export-displaying-svg-image-from-embedded-url and 
https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-tutorial

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but since I don't have data, only an image, I don't find a way to create a page (without data) and add the image.

Comment: I ended up creating a "No Data" page with the chart, thanks for pointing to jasper

Comment: SVG isn't supported in PDF. Or do you want to convert SVG to vector graphics, is that your question? If that is what you want, you could combine Apache BATIK with https://github.com/rototor/pdfbox-graphics2d

Comment: I embeded an SVG with JasperReports, are you saying that the SVG was converted behind the scenes?

Comment: Most likely. One would have to see the PDF.